# select function recognize Enter key (from user input) as client request

Tags: c++

I have a server-client program, and I know it a little bit lack on reproduction steps but I think it more knowledge question then implementation.
I have the main program that creates the server thread and also expects user input from the terminal
the server routine is:

```
void Server::ServerRoutin(std::shared_ptr<BaseStrategy< Derived, Event_Type > > st,std::shared_ptr<SMDSSubscriber> md)
{
fd_set temp;
int active=0;
bool flag = true;

while(flag)
{
    temp =m_active_fd_set; //  m_active_fd_set is fd_set
    if ((active = select (FD_SETSIZE, &temp, NULL, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&m_active_fd_set);
        FD_SET(m_serverSocket->GetSocket(), &m_active_fd_set);
        perror ("select");
        continue;
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(m_serverSocket->GetSocket(),&temp))
    {
        m_clients.push_back(m_serverSocket->AcceptClient());
        FD_SET (m_clients[m_clients.size()-1]->GetSocket(),&m_active_fd_set);
    }

    if(FD_ISSET(0, &temp))
    {

        flag= false;
        break;
    }
//some more code
```

but when the user enters user input **not via the client-side** but from the main program, the select function in the server think it got a request from the client and start running

this is the thread creation :

```
 std::thread t2(&programManager< BacStrategy < SREXOrderEventHandler >, SREXOrderEventHandler >, bac , nullptr);
```

Comment: what's in `m_active_fd_set`?

Comment: it of type fd_set